# Is there a way to keep a carrotwood tree from bearing fruit? Something similar to a solution used for olive trees?

Tags: trees

Want to find a way to keep a carrotwood tree from bearing and dropping fruit

Comment: I'm curious- what solution do they use to stop olive trees bearing fruit? Where are  you in the world?

Comment: Pictures help, I am intrigued to see carrotwood

Comment: I have this same question. We planted a carrot wood a few years ago and we love the shade and cover that it provides, but the seeds it drops this time of year are a mess! Would love to be able to prevent it from flowering/seeding.

Comment: For background this tree is highly invasive and is banned in Florida as a noxious weed.  Removal is a good idea https://www.invasive.org/weedcd/pdfs/wgw/carrotwood.pdf